# Let $W$ be a vector space and let $U$ and $V$ be finite-dimensional subspaces.

Tags: vector-spaces

a) Show that $U ∩ V$ is a subspace of $W$.
b) Show that $U + V = \{u + v : u \in U, v \in V\}$ is a subspace of $W$.
c) Show that $\dim(U+V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U ∩ V)$.

I have no idea where to start.  Any help?

Comment: Can you name the axioms for a vectorspace?

Comment: Let X, Y, Z be in V, and let r,s be scalars:
1. Commutativity: X + Y = Y + X,
2. Associativity of vector addition: X + (Y + Z) = (X + Y) + Z
3. Additive Identity
4. Additive Inverse
5. Associativity of scalars: r(sX) = (rs)X
6. Distributivity of Scalar Sums: (r+s)X = rX + sX
7. Distributivity of Vector Sums: r(X + Y) = rX + rY
8. Scalar Multiplication Identity: 1*X = X

Comment: Whenever any sort of subobject is defined as a subset that is closed under something, then the intersection of two or more (including infinitely many) subobjects is a subobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part a) Use the definition of what a subspace means. It is first closed under vector addition, has an identity, and is closed under scalars.  First show closure under vector addition which is basically proving this:  If $x,y\in U\cap V\implies x+y\in U+V$. Now the identity is trivial to show. Since $U$ and $V$ are finite subspaces it follows by definition that... And for scalar multiplication. Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ where $r$ will be a scalar. Let $x\in U\cap V\implies x\in U$ and $x\in V$. It follows that since $U$ and $V$ are subspaces then $rx\in U$ and $rx\in V \implies rx\in U\cap V$. Hence we conclude...

For part b) Same thing. Let $x\in U+V$. First show closure. That is if $x,y\in U+V$ where $x=a+b$ and $y=c+d$ where $a,c\in U$ and $b,d\in V$ then we see $x+y=(a+b)+(c+d)$ which is still an element of the set $U+V$. For the identity its easy. I will denote $0$ to be the identity both in $U$ and $V$ since it follows by definition of a subspace. Thus $0=0+0\in U+V$ And lastly scalar multiplication which I will leave up to you.

For part c) Recall what dimension means and remember $U+V$ is a set.

I forgot to put arrows on top of the elements but they are all vectors. So you can place arrows for clarity.

Comment: Okay this all makes sense, but I'm confused in part (c) why I'll need to remember U+V rather than U ∩ V?

Also, for part (c) how would I find a basis?  Do I simply state that U and V have bases if the linear combination of vectors in U and V are linearly independent and span in the respective subspaces?